# IPstatic : don't seem to have all the variable for eth0

Tags: static, dns, ip, debian

I want to have a static ip for my debian : 192.168.249.5

This is my inferfaces file : /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
adress 192.168.249.5
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.152.255
dns-nameservers 192.168.249.5
```

When I do :

```
/etc/init.d/networking stop
/etc/init.d/networking start
```

I have :
Configuring network interfaces... Don't seem to have all the variables for eth0/inet.
Failed to bring up eth0.

I don't understand.

Comment: 9 years later..... you spelled 'address' wrong in your config.

Answer (score 4):

Please check out the [documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Configuring_the_interface_manually). You should probably write the "adress" as "address" for this to work. Also your gateway address is not possible. Might it be 254?

Comment: Do you use a 255.255.0.0 (/16) netmask in your network (or is the 152 just a typo)? If not the gateway can not be reached with your current settings (even if you change it to 254).